# Group dataframe by two columns and then find average count based on one of the groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-science

Really struggling to get this solution. Suppose I have the dataframe below:

| SEX | ITEM | Some other column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M | Socks | 233 |
| M | Socks | 1 |
| M | Hat | 2 |
| F | Socks | 3 |
| F | Hat | 3 |
| F | Hat | 6 |
| F | Hat | 2 |

I would like to find the average number of occurrences of each ITEM based on the SEX group

| SEX | ITEM | Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M | Socks | 0.6666 |
| M | Hat | 0.3333 |
| F | Socks | 0.25 |
| F | Hat | 0.75 |

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `df.groupby("SEX")["ITEM"].value_counts(normalize=1)`

Comment: This is the best solution for my situation. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['SEX'], df['ITEM'],normalize='index').stack().reset_index(name='average')
Out[36]: 
  SEX   ITEM   average
0   F    Hat  0.750000
1   F  Socks  0.250000
2   M    Hat  0.333333
3   M  Socks  0.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the function `groupby()` with the `count()` aggregation, and then divide the relevant columns to get the ratio

```
df2 = df.groupby(['SEX']).count().reset_index()
df1 = df.groupby(['SEX', 'ITEM']).count().reset_index()
df1['SEX_count'] = df1['SEX'].apply(lambda x: df2['ITEM'][df2['SEX']==x].values[0])
df1['Average'] = df1['Someothercolumn'] / df1['SEX_count']
df1 = df1.drop(columns=['Someothercolumn', 'SEX_count'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  SEX   ITEM   Average
0   F    Hat  0.750000
1   F  Socks  0.250000
2   M    Hat  0.333333
3   M  Socks  0.666667
```

Another great answer suggested by @user3483203 (I like this one!)

```
print(df.groupby(['SEX'], as_index=False)['ITEM'].value_counts(normalize=1))

  SEX   ITEM  proportion
0   F    Hat    0.750000
1   F  Socks    0.250000
2   M  Socks    0.666667
3   M    Hat    0.333333
```

Comment: Thank you. user3483203 comment under my post is a more succinct solution for my problem.

Comment: ah nice.. Let me document down that answer for learning sake!